# Advice in edit form design for JSF

Tags: jsf

I have a complex Bean object that I want to update. Because it is too much complex, it can't be edited in the DataTable (inplace editing). Let's say that my page have this structure:

-> Input Form

-> DataTable for Listing

So I save the object using the **Input Form** and it appears inside the **DataTable**. This part is easy. Now, I need to edit the object inside the **DataTable**. Since the object is too much complex, it is not viable to edit in-place. So I must pick the row data and put it in a form to be able to sumbit it.

My problem is, I haven't come to a way of editing the data that I would like.

I've done it in multiple ways.

1. I've created a page only for the edit. I call the page passing the object's ID in the URL.
2. I copied the **Input Form** inside a Dialog. While this is great for editing, using a dialog had led me into problems (complex validations patterns, dialogs inside dialogs, etc).
3. I put the row data back into the **Input Form** and use Primefaces-Extensions spotlight component to ensure that the user will only work within the form. I've added a button to cancel edition also.

I didn't like any of them, although the third is the best of them, to me. But I'm also out of ideas of how to design data editing. Do you guys have some edit designs that you would like to share?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a user interface challenge, not a JSF challenge. I don't think there will be a "JSF silver bullet component" to solve your problem. IMO. You might target your question to a wider audience, but probably not StackOverflow.

Comment: Breakdown the GodBean in smaller reusable parts.

Comment: @DavidS, I understand what you are saying, you're right. I'm not seeking JSF miracles though, just JSF users experience with complex Bean edit forms.

Comment: @BalusC, I would gladly break the bean if it was possible, but the complexity is in the bean itself and it's rules, not in its parts. I do not see how I could break it or any other bean that suits the case...

Comment: @Dalton: as DavidS stated, it is not a jsf issue and you'll get better advice asking in some generic ui-design related forum